# Cannot define method `vertices' because no Objective-C stub was pre-compiled for types

Tags: rubymotion

I have just been using RubyMotion and Joybox today.

After installed RubyMotion 2.22 and Joybox 1.1.1 (with rvm 1.25.15, ruby 2.0.0-p353@joybox, on Mac OS X 10.9), and go on with Joybox round 1 article, just after 'motion create --template=joybox-ios test01' and 'rake', I keep getting this error:

Cannot define method `vertices' because no Objective-C stub was pre-compiled for types`^{CGPoint=ff}@:'. Make sure you properly link with the framework or library that defines this message.

I spent hours searching on the net but still can't find a solution. I'm wondering could someone give me some insight?

Things I tried:

- Checked https://github.com/rubymotion/Joybox/issues/42
- Reinstalled xcode command line tools.
- Removed/Re-installed Joybox gem.
- Re-installed RubyMotion

Thank you,

-Long

Comment: Did you try `rake clean`? I had a similar issue, and this solved it (also had to update RubyMotion, as it was a bug there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated to version 2.22 of RubyMotion and this caused the same issue for me.

Downgrade RubyMotion

```
sudo motion update --cache-version=2.20
```

and set your rubymotion to `$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion2.20/lib")`
 in you Rakefile.

Comment: And run ``rake clean`` to make sure old files are still not their from any previous build